# Websocket with HTTPS (liferay, tomcat 7, WSS)

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, websocket, spring-websocket

I am actively looking for a solution to this issue with HTTPS request for connecting with WebSocket.

I am using the following:

- Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.10
- Liferay 6.2

When I was using Localhost:9080 at that time WebSocket was running properly, but then I switched to the secured domain (https://www.example.com). now WebSocket is not connecting.

Here is connection code:

(working fine with `HTTP://localhost:9080`)

```
var socket = new SockJS("/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp");
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({meeting: getMeetingId(), userId: connectedUserId}, connectCallback);
```

Exception in logs:

```
   May 23, 2020 12:16:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/UniflowEservices-portlet] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=https://example.com:443/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp/038/4cc54for/xhr_streaming?t=1590236173423; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure for request https://example.com:443/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp/038/4cc54for/xhr_streaming?t=1590236173423; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "<async-supported>true</async-supported>" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container
```

error in console:

```
Opening Web Socket...

POST https://example.com/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp/268/32aanmie/xhr_streaming?t=1590241224478 500 (Internal Server Error)

GET https://example.com/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp/268/ulgaar3z/eventsource net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

GET https://example.com/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp/268/zsqhls14/htmlfile?c=_jp.an2dcfd 500 (Internal Server Error)

POST https://example.com/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp/268/cwtosngm/xhr?t=1590241227704 500 (Internal Server Error)

GET https://example.com/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp/268/5ma3lpr5/jsonp?c=_jp.awlvof3 net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Whoops! Lost connection to https: //example.com/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp
```

I tried the following,

1) code in js:

```
const url = 'wss://example.com/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp';
let socket = new WebSocket(url);    
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({meeting: getMeetingId(), userId: connectedUserId}, connectCallback);
```

Exception in the console:

```
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/UniflowE services-portlet/WS/stomp' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

2) code in js:

```
var socket = new SockJS("http:/ /localhost:9080/UniflowEservices-portlet/WS/stomp");
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);    
stompClient.connect({meeting: getMeetingId(), userId: connectedUserId}, connectCallback);
```

Exception in the console:

no exception (But only working for not secure https sites)

Notes: If I allow insecure content in the site (from site setting of the browser) then it is making WebSocket connection.

I read hundreds of articles regarding Websocket but not found any relevant.

Comment: why do you try to fix client side code while error happens at server side? server gave you a hint already "...Async support must be enabled...".

Comment: Thank you @MaximSagaydachny for your answer, but we already checked that way but not working for us.

when I use the ready-made link from website example(with was) it is connecting using out local stomp.min.js.